# Garry's Mod Add on Folder?

Tags: games, steam, plugins, hidden-files

Hi i'm trying to install the CSS add on to GMOD but for the life of me cant find the add on folder, Or the steam folder itself for that matter.

When I try load the folder via GMOD it comes up that the folder is :

/home/dylan/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/GarrysMod

But It Doesn't Exist according to my laptop i try to look for it but it cant get past:

/home/dylan/

and then .local is where it stops and i cant find it. Anywhere. I mean there are other .local files in different location but they all have different things in.

So i was just wondering what i was doing wrong and why i cant find the add on folder for garrys mod, i'm tired of seeing the fricking pink and black checkers on my screen.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any directory that starts with a . is a hidden directory.

From a file manager you want to select show hidden (either right click, or its in the top menu under view)

For example, if you open a terminal it opens up in your home directory.

If you type

```
 ls
```

This will show you what you normally would see on a file manager, but if you

```
 ls -a
```

You will see all the hidden dot files.

Comment: XD omg i feel dumb haha thank you soo much ive been trying to do this for like 7 hours X'D

Comment: Don't feel dumb, you just learned something new. If this helped you, please mark it as accepted if you don't mind.